# Throaty growl when accelerating

Tags: engine, noise

I have a 2013 Chevy Impala V6 and when I push the throttle down the engine has a throaty growl, sounds good but I can't imagine why it makes it. Once the speed is accomplished it quietns down. Anyone have an idea what this is.

Comment: Isn't this literally just the car accelerating?

Answer (score 1):

Well, a couple of things spring to mind:

One, the silencers may have blown the silencing material out or,

Two the exhaust system could have been changed recently...

Three, it could be an intake noise - if the air filter has been removed or it may have failed.

However, funnily enough there are several people who would pay good money for that noise :)

Comment: @Zaid they could all answer the situation, and there is no guarantee the OP will cone back with the real problem... All things yhat either the OP or anyone else should check - I don’t need an reply though...

Comment: @Zaid edited so I am now posting possible answers : three in one for good value and they are not questions...

Comment: That looks much better :)